# Best ETL tool for converting XML to a table

Tags: sql-server, xml, xsd, xml-parsing

I need to convert >500 XML's to tables that I can query. I have the XSD that I use to verify the structure. I was considering using notepad++ to structure the files. Is that a good idea, if not what is better? The end goal is either flatfiles with the same columns or directly to SQL

Example #1 XML

```
(...)
<Customer>
  <CustomerID>1</CustomerID>
  <Address>
     <Street>John Street</Street>
     <Number>6</Number>
     <Apartment>68</Apartment>
     <City>New York</City>
     <Zip>10068</Zip>
  </Address>
  <Firstname>John</Firstname>
  <LastName>Doe<LastName/>
</Customer>
(...)
```

Example #2 XML

```
(...)
<Customer>
  <CustomerID>2</CustomerID>
  <Address>
     <Street>Wall Street</Street>
     <City>New York</City>
  </Address>
  <Firstname>James Smith</Firstname>
</Customer>
(...)
```

Example #3 XML

```
(...)
<n1:Customer>
  <n1:CustomerID>3</n1:CustomerID>
  <n1:Address>
     <n1:Apartment>32</n1:Apartment>
     <n1:City>Chicago</n1:City>
  </n1:Address>
</n1:Customer>
(...)
```

Comment: What is your RDBMS and its version?

Comment: you can import xml to sql server using OPENROWSET then use OPENXML to extract individual columns

Comment: @miriamka - SQL Server

Comment: @Vasya - That is one possibility, but I'm afraid that SQL Server is not flexible enough if the are minor corruption issues in the file (e.g. unescaped special characters) that might break the 2 GB/XML Column constraint

Comment: You can use SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS). It has a built-in **XML Source** Adapter.

Comment: The language you know the best and has an XML library.  My preference on Windows is Net/Core.  Either with Power Shell, c#, or VBNET.  The SQL language in SSMS is limited and tasks like this are better done in another language.

Comment: @miriamka I don't have a SSIS license I'm afraid. So it needs to be the approach suggested by Vasya.

Comment: @jdweng For me that would either be R or Python. But to my knowledge, I think neither of these maintains the XML libs because very few are using it. Any thoughts on those two?

Comment: Don't know either very well.  I found : https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.html

Comment: SSIS doesn't need any additional license on top of the regular MS SQL Server license.

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example: (1) Real XML sample, (2) Target SQL Server table structure, i.e. CREATE TABLE ... corresponding to #1.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions. I'm going to do R - primarily due to what @jdweng wrote.